# How to create a logical vector in R when I know where the logic is true?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a logical vector from the information where the logic is TRUE. Is there a reverse `which` function? I've tried this:
`which(x) <- c(2,3,4)`
Is there a reason why this method is not working, and is there an alternative method? I've also tried initializing the vector.

Comment: `1:5 %in% c(2,3,4)` ?

Comment: I would add to @bergant's comment if the initial vector is `v1`, `seq_along(v1) %in% ind` where `ind <- 2:4` Or another option is `v2 <- numeric(length(v1));v2[ind] <- 0; as.logical(v2)`

Comment: @akrun I think you meant `v2 <- rep(1, length(v1))`. `numeric` gives an all-zeros vector.

Comment: No, I meant to create v2 as a vector of 0's.  Then change the values to 1 from the 'ind' position. and we convert it to logical vector so that 0 coerces to FALSE and 1 to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the full code you are running?  And what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to return a logical vector of the locations of values that match a given range?

In that case, you can simply write x==y to find all values of x that are equal to y.  There are sexier ways of doing this, but here's a quick and dirty example:

```
# Create some random data
set.seed(327)
x <- sample(1:10, 100, replace=TRUE)

# Now let's see where we can find 1, 2, and 3.  The pipe | is R's "or" operator
x==1|x==2|x==3

# How many matches did we get?
table(x==1|x==2|x==3)
```